# is it possible to have Different values with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I have a person object that I am sorting:

```
 persCriteria = criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(Session)  
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc("LastName"))
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc("FirstName"));
```

I also have an attribute called `CommonName`.

What do i want? Well I want to be able to sort on `CommonName` if the person has a `CommonName` else sort on `FirstName`(first).

Now I'm wondering is it possible to indicate  via *NHibernate* that it should orderby `CommonName` if the person has a `CommonName` else order by `FirstName`? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. We can use Conditional projection:

```
var conditionalOrderBy = Projections.Conditional
(
    Restrictions.IsNull("CommonName") // or LastName, not sure from a question snippet
  , Projections.Property("FirstName")
  , Projections.Property("CommonName") // or LastName
);

var list = criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session)  
  .AddOrder(new Order(conditionalOrderBy, true))
  .List<Person>()
;
```

And SQL statement we get would be like:

```
...
ORDER BY (CASE when this_.CommonName IS NULL 
  THEN this_.FirstName 
  ELSE this_.CommonName END) 
 ASC
```

Comment: worked perfectly! sorry for the vauge description...i was at it for a whiile and it seemed perfectly clear to me but now a day l see that it could be kind of hard to understand.

If i might trouble you a bit more...if you have the time could you perhaps provied me with tutorial links about nhibernate? i had a task that had to be done via nhibernate and nopw it is solved but i never got in to it in detal since i had trouble finding good sites.

Thanks alot!